# axios calls backend-api but theres no data displayed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i want to make a local API call for retrieving a base64 encoded image from my local backend.
The logging on the backend shows that axios calls the api.
However on my frontend there is no data displayed. All i get is an empty page.
What have i done wrong?
Thanks i appreciate any help.

```
<template>
  <p>{{ this.result }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      result: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("url")
      .then((response) => (this.result = response));
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Data in axios is under `data` key. Change your `then()` call in mounted function to `.then((response) => (this.result = response.data));`

Comment: what does url contain?

Comment: `.then(response => console.log(response))` might provide some useful info.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! @Anastazy I kinda missed that. I did change that, but I still get an empty page. The "url" is a placeholder for my backend API, that part does work my logger verifies that the API gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was "Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing".

I had to enable cross-origin resource sharing for my Vue application. This was done in Spring Boot with @CrossOrigin.